# Checking third character in string using regex

Tags: regex, cocoa, ios5, nspredicate

I have to check the third character in the string. I'm trying to do that with NSPredicate. I thought the regular expression should be ..3* so it will find every string with third character 3. But its not working and I did try some others approaches without success :(. Can someone help me ?

simple code to checking

```
- (IBAction)btnCheckPerformClick:(id)sender {
_chkOk.state = NO;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like[c] %@", _txtRegExpression.stringValue];
NSLog(@"%@", predicate);
if([predicate evaluateWithObject:_txtCheckingText.stringValue])
    _chkOk.state = YES;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LIKE` operator in the predicate format language only understands simple wildcards (`?` and `*`). You need to use `MATCHES` if you want to use a regular expression.

See the [Predicate Programming Guide (String Comparisons)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1) for more details.

Alternatively, use `NSRegularExpression`.

Comment: Great it's working with `..3.*`. I was trying this as well but just with `..3*`

Comment: If you just use `..3` as your regular expression it will match blahblah3blah.   Make sure you anchor it as per my answer.

Comment: Not realy. The `..3` will match just `aa3` not `aa3a` or `aaaaa3aa`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one more dot - use `..3.*`. You probably also want to anchor it to the beginning and end of the string using `^..3.*$`.

Comment: You don't need the `.*$` at the end of that regex, it doesn't do anything for this use case.

Comment: Probably not but it may make a difference when dealing with multiline inputs.

Comment: `Predicate:SELF LIKE[c] "^..3.*$"
SearchingText:aa3aaa`
The same, not working.

Answer (score 1):

`..3*` means any two characters followed by an optional 3, anywhere in your input.  You want `^..3`, which means any two characters followed by 3, starting from the beginning of the line.

Comment: `Predicate:SELF LIKE[c] "^..3"
SearchingText:aa3aaa`
Does't work

Comment: As @omz noted, you need to use MATCHES rather than LIKE for regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

```
..3*
```

That regular expression doesn't do what you want.

It says, any two characters, then any number of 3's (including no 3's)

How about this one?

```
^..3.*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using `NSString` method `subStringWithRange:` instead?
If you are not comfortable with Regular Expressions, do not rush into it. Use something that works. Cocoa's Regular Expression implementation is not the easiest thing to get started with.
Grab your string, then compare it to whatever.
You can loop over the string to get every 3rd character just as easily.

```
NSString *aString = @"abc";
NSString *thirdCharacterOnly;
if (aString.length >= 3) {

    for (NSUInteger i = 2; i < aString.length; i += 3) {
        thirdCharacterOnly = [aString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 1)];
        if ([thirdCharacterOnly isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
                // Do something.
        }
    }

} else {
        // do something different.
}
```

If you want more on Regular Expressions get [THE book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007I8S1X0). 3 chapters will get you up to speed. Learn Regular Expressions with Ruby, Python or Perl first. It will save your brain.